# Can I use aquarium TapSafe on my potted spider plants?

Tags: houseplants, chemicals

I have some potted spider plants in my office. They've all got the classic "burnt tips".

If I treat their water with aquarium TapSafe, will this help re: fluoride and other nasties? Or is there something I'm missing that could kill them doing this?

Comment: Chlorine evaporates if you fill your container and leave it overnight to come to room temp. You can hardly overwater a spider, but underwatering can make for brown tips, too.

Comment: Why add material you do not understand to the water ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most aquarium water products will neutralize the chlorine or chloramine added to  city tap water.  Removing fluoride is most commonly done with a water filter and I recommend you use a water filter to get water that's good for your plant